# java neural network programming error

Tags: java, runtime-error, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, netbeans-8

This is my program code and it give the errors mentioned at the end of the document, when i run the program. FYI, no compilation errors occur.

**Program**

```
   package javaapplication3;

/**
 *
 * @author ashish
 */
import org.neuroph.core.*;
import org.neuroph.core.data.DataSet;
import org.neuroph.core.data.DataSetRow;
import org.neuroph.nnet.*;
        public class JavaApplication3 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    // create new perceptron network
    NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork = new Perceptron(2, 1);
    // create training set
    DataSet trainingSet =
   new DataSet(2, 1);
   // add training data to training set (logical OR function)
   trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow (new double[]{0, 0},new double[{0}));
   trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow (new double[]{0, 1},new double[{1}));
   trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow (new double[]{1, 0},new double[{1}));
   trainingSet. addRow (new DataSetRow (new double[]{1, 1},new double[{1}));
   // learn the training set
   neuralNetwork.learn(trainingSet);
   // save the trained network into file
   neuralNetwork.save("or_perceptron.nnet");

  /*// load the saved network
 NeuralNetwork neuralNetwork =
 NeuralNetwork.createFromFile(“or_perceptron.nnet”);
 // set network input
 neuralNetwork.setInput(1, 1);
 // calculate network
 neuralNetwork.calculate();
 // get network output
 double[] networkOutput = neuralNetwork.getOutput();
  */   }

  }
```

**Error** This is the runtime error which i cannot solve. I tried slf4j folder by adding it to the libraries but that didnt work also. Please help me.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
    at org.neuroph.core.learning.LearningRule.<init>(LearningRule.java:65)
    at org.neuroph.core.learning.IterativeLearning.<init>(IterativeLearning.java:72)
    at org.neuroph.core.learning.SupervisedLearning.<init>(SupervisedLearning.java:82)
    at org.neuroph.nnet.learning.LMS.<init>(LMS.java:44)
    at org.neuroph.nnet.learning.PerceptronLearning.<init>(PerceptronLearning.java:40)
    at org.neuroph.nnet.learning.BinaryDeltaRule.<init>(BinaryDeltaRule.java:48)
    at org.neuroph.nnet.Perceptron.createNetwork(Perceptron.java:114)
    at org.neuroph.nnet.Perceptron.<init>(Perceptron.java:56)
    at javaapplication3.JavaApplication3.main(JavaApplication3.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 9 more
C:\Users\ashish\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: also the class name is not changed its the same as the project and application name

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path to slf4j jar (or folder that contains .class files) to the **classpath**.

See here how: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html